# Python scripting in GDB

Tags: python, gdb

Would it be possible to retrieve the result of an instruction as a Python string? As an example: I could execute "x/i $eip" from within python using `gdb.execute`. Would I be able to fetch the result of the same as a Python string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the "to_string" argument to `gdb.execute`:

```
str = gdb.execute('some command', to_string = True)
```